# What is the history behind CAR 105.01(2)?

Tags: regulations, transport-canada

[Canadian Aviation Regulation 105.01(2)](http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/SOR-96-433/FullText.html#s-105.01) states:

"No person shall conduct an aerial sightseeing flight, or any portion of an aerial sightseeing flight, in the control zone of the Québec/Jean Lesage International Airport unless the flight commences at that airport."

I find it odd that this is a law, and not just a NOTAM.

Does anyone know why this was added to the CARs in 1998?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, it's because of complaints about noise. From [the Canada Gazette, Vol. 132, No. 2, pp.98-103](http://publications.gc.ca/gazette/archives/p2/1998/1998-01-21/pdf/g2-13202.pdf):

> The regulation reflects the Minister’s desire to have increased
>   oversight of sightseeing flights within the Québec/Jean-Lesage
>   International Airport control zone.
>
> [...]
>
> The regulations are
>   intended to prevent frequent low level flights for aerial sightseeing
>   purposes over the built-up area within the Québec/Jean-Lesage
>   International Airport control zone and to stop commercial
>   passenger-carrying aerial sightseeing flights from using the Lac
>   St-Augustin, Quebec aerodrome for either take-offs or landings. The
>   prohibition of low level commercial aerial sightseeing flights within
>   the entire Québec/JeanLesage International Airport control zone is
>   intended to ensure that such operations do not relocate to another
>   nearby lake and recommence sightseeing operations from that location.
>
> [...]
>
> Since the late sixties and, increasingly, in recent years,
>   Transport Canada has received numerous complaints from citizens about
>   the noise of floatplanes flying over several towns and cities in the
>   Quebec City area.

The Gazette goes into a lot more detail about the background, impact, consultation process etc. 25 local mayors signed a letter to Transport Canada asking for action, so I guess it came down to political pressure in the end.